# Removing trailing zeros at the end of a dataset in multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have user running a macro that formats specific worksheets within a workbook. After running this macro, the user has trailing zeros that generate in multiple worksheets and they are looking for a way to remove those zeros from each worksheet.

Initially, I provided them with the vba below but this is only useful for a single worksheet.

I was curious if there was an easy way to alter the VBA below to accommodate multiple worksheets, or would I need to rewrite the VBA altogether.

I have provided an image that will hopefully help visualize what I mean by trailing zeros....Feel free to request additional information. Thank you ahead of time for the help!

```vb
Sub contentkiller()
Dim lastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
 'Find last row in col C
 lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'clear data
 .Range("A" & lastRow + 1 & ":Y" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
End With
End Sub
```

[Trailing Zeros at the Bottom of a Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZUpr.png)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the Macro that creates the issue in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through all worksheets. Hopefully they are similar in structure. Something like this should work.

```
Sub runAll()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     Call contentkiller(ws)
    Next ws
End Sub


Private Sub contentkiller(ws As Worksheet)
   Dim lastRow As Long
   With ws
     'Find last row in col C
     lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'clear data
    .Range("A" & lastRow + 1 & ":Y" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, each sheet is different in column count and row count. The VBA I sent over was built for a single worksheet, removing zeros from one column. The new intel is run through each worksheet and remove any trailing info using column A as the bottom of dataset. It looks like the VBA you provided removes from the single worksheet (same as the original VBA). To be honest, I'm not sure how to proceed I am not able to provide the workbook for privacy reason but I am happy to provide any additional information that would help.

Comment: Thank you for providing an option....hopefully we can work through this and find a solve

Comment: @jasnpark Your original question involved handling procedures on different sheets, and you received two answers that address this. The fact that you have now changed up your question means VBasic2008 and I spent time answering your question and have no rep increase to show for it. Looking at your profile, it appears you've never accepted an answer despite receiving quality responses. I'd suggest you click accept to good answers and consider learning how to ask more specific questions that directly address your issues..

Comment: I sincerely apologize for my approach to this issue. I am new to both VBA and using stackoverflow, as I’m sure you noticed when viewing my profile; I have only ask two questions since creating an account. Additionally, I apologize if my response to the resolutions veered away from my submission, that was not the intent. I was merely trying to elaborate on the situation. The problem remains the same: I have a workbook with a multiple worksheet (each different), trailing zeros need to be removed from rows below the main dataset in each worksheet.

Comment: I did test out both options provided and was not able to get them to work. My hope was that we could find a resolution and I could appropriately mark up the reps.....since reading your comment I have tried to mark up the reps and continue to get a messages saying "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to case a vote, but your feedback has been recorded". Is it possible that is the reason you are not seeing my previous attempts? Happy to send an image if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Trailing...

- In each worksheet of a workbook, it will find the bottom-most non-empty cell in the first column of its used range. If the cell is located above the bottom-most cell(s) of the used range, it will clear the contents in all of the rows of the used range, that are below the found cell.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveTrailing()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If you plan to copy this code into each workbook then use:
    'Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim lCell As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ulRow As Long
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange
            With .Columns(1)
                Set lCell = Nothing
                Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                    .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            End With
            If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
                lRow = lCell.Row
                ulRow = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
                If lRow < ulRow Then
                    Set crg = .Rows(lRow - .Row + 2).Resize(ulRow - lRow)
                    crg.ClearContents
                End If
            'Else
                ' empty first column
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like this VBA is executing off the same worksheet and not removing from the others. referencing my comment above...it may be due to the differing worksheets (each worksheet has a different column count and row count).

Comment: Thank you for sending over a potential fix...I am hoping we can resolve this without digging too deep.